# How do I use an array element as an argument in a UDF?

Tags: excel, vba

This function works exactly as intended, but if I replace 'Rank' with 'Merc(98)' as an argument I receive an error message, `Compile error: Expected: )`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
UDF to lookup DMs on Skills_Tables_DMs table
  Function RankDMs(WhichTable, Rank)
    RankDMs = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(WhichTable, (Range("Skills_Tables_DMs")), (Rank + 1), False)
  End Function
```

Comment: Where do you replace, in function definition like `Function RankDMs(WhichTable, Merc(98))` or when you call the function?

Comment: In the definition.  Would I be right in thinking that this might be the problem?

Comment: `Merc(98)` will be then array with 99 elements. And you need to pass an argument which will be an array. Is this how you think of it? Because next you don't use correct reference to array item.

Comment: No, I am using Merc(98) as the 99th element of an array.  I certainly don't want to be passing any reference to (almost) the whole array.  Could you clarify you statement 'Because next you don't use correct reference to array item'?

Comment: @KazJaw.  Thanks, please accept a +1 to your comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the below doesn't help then you're going to need to either explain in more detail what you're trying to do or (better) include more of the relevant code.

```
Sub Tester()
'...
Dim rv
'...
    rv = RankDMs(someValueHere, 5)
    'or
    rv = RankDMs(someValueHere, Merc(98))
'...
End Sub


Function RankDMs(WhichTable, Rank)
    RankDMs = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(WhichTable, _
                  Range("Skills_Tables_DMs"), (Rank + 1), False)
End Function
```

Note I changed this:

```
(Range("Skills_Tables_DMs"))
```

to:

```
Range("Skills_Tables_DMs")
```

*Though it's not really critical in this case (since either form will work)*, you should note that the two are not equivalent: in the first case the extra parentheses cause an evaluation of the *Value* of the range, resulting in a Variant array, but the second results in a `Range` object.  You can see this in the Immediate pane of the VB editor by comparing these two:

```
? typeName((Range("A1:A5")))   ' >> Variant()
? typeName(Range("A1:A5"))     ' >> Range
```

Comment: Many thanks for that.  Having experimented with your code I can now get mine to work the way I want it to, but more importantly I understand what I was doing wrong - I was confusing defining the function and calling it. +1